# How to handle a unit test Exception in python

Tags: python, unit-testing

The code below is a unit test code to test the original code

```
import unittest
from drones import Drone, DroneStore

class DroneTest(unittest.TestCase):
def test_add_success(self):
    drone = Drone('Drone1', 1, False)
    store = DroneStore()
    store.add(drone)
    self.assertEqual(drone, store.get(1))
    print(store.get(1).name)


def test_add_raiseException_true(self):
    drone = Drone('Drone1', 1, False)
    store = DroneStore()
    store.add(drone)
    self.assertEqual(drone, store.get(1))

    with self.assertRaises(Exception) as context:
        store.add(drone)
    self.assertTrue('Drone already exists in store' in str(context.exception)


def test_remove_success(self):
    drone = Drone('Drone1', 1, False)
    store = DroneStore()
    store.add(drone)
    self.assertEqual(drone, store.get(1))
    print(store.get(1).name)

    store.remove(drone)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This is the partial original code I get : [image: ScreenShot]

It looks like I get error from the function named "test_add_raiseException_true",  this function is created to test if the 'add' function from original code raises an exception if a drone is already exist in the store

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: one thing for sure, missing `)` in `self.assertTrue`

Comment: @Gang Oh lol, my mistake

Comment: @Patrick I think my question should be how do I show that it raises an exception when there is a drone exist in the store

Comment: The `DroneStore` class is a mess, the `add()` try to change the `drone.id`?!, the test class seems to be ok

Comment: cause when I run the code, "test_add_raiseException_true" function doesn't show if the exception has been raised

Comment: Yes, the default id is 0 when the store has nothing, the add() function then adds the id by 1 if there is a drone added to the store

Comment: the `self._drones` is a dict with a key, supposed to be drone.id, if `add` change the drone.id, that is a serious flaw. same as changing a person's name, and try to find the person by name

Comment: increment `self.__lastid` when add, do nothing while `delete()`?

Comment: If the `Exception` isn't raised, then `assertRaises` will raise `AssertionError` and fail the test.  Is the test passing?

Comment: The `get()`, `if not id in self._drones`, should really be `if not id in self._drones.keys()`, or get() will always return None